# Why is DayJs Causing Site to Freeze and Not Load?

Tags: javascript, dayjs

So, I have a site that requires `day.js`, and I've had some experience on previous sites, and it's worked fine, and loaded fast. But as soon as I try to use it on a new site, it just causes it my site to freeze up. I've tried using `defer` and `async` but it just won't work. I've used a local file, and it still won't work. I used Chrome DevTool's Network Panel, and it says everything sent a `200 OK` response, so I don't know what to do.

```js
let start=dayjs().startOf("day").add(2,"day")
while(start.$d!=0){start=start.subtract(1,"day")}
document.write(start)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>repl.it</title>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js" async></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here a demo is, it won't load here either. Eventually, it just says the page is unresponsive, and to wait or close it.

Comment: It does not work here simply because you have not included the library.

Comment: Yes, I have. If you looked at the HTML, you'll see I have a script tag pointing towards `dayjs`, and Stack Overflow's own way of including libraries just inserts a script tag. I'm unclear on what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the property $d is the date string, something like `Sun May 02 2021 00:00:00`. I think you're looking for $D, which is the day, something like `4`. Additionally, you wait until the date is 0, but that can't happen because dates start on the first day of the month. You could instead do `start = start.date(1)` which would instantly set the date to 1 without using loops.

The official docs can be found [here](https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/date).